# derivative of multivariable recursive function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, recursion

Given a recursive function
$$
f(x,y,z) = f(h(x),g(y,z),z)
$$
I want to get the derivative of the function to $z$
$$
{d\over dz } f(x,y,z) = ?
$$
My guess is
$$
{d \over dz}f(x,y,z) = f'(h(x),g(y,z),z) g'(y,z) {dy \over dz}
$$

But I'm not sure if I'm right, especially the last part $dy \over dz$ because the $y$ for the next call of $f$ is $g(y,z)$ and it is affected by $z$.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the chain rule properly:

if $\phi(x, y, z) = f(h(x), g(y, z))$, we have:

$\frac{d \phi}{dz}(x, y, z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}(h(x), g(y, z)) \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(y, z)$.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misuse of the notation so I appended the fix.
By the way I think yours is not recursive?

Comment: I'm familiar with recursive functions in computer science, but I'm struggling to see what you mean here. Can you clear that up?

Comment: Sure. Basically I want the general form of derivate of $f(x,y,z) = f(h(x),g(y,z),z)$ where $f$ is recursive.

Comment: I got that part :D your definition of $f$ does not suffice though.
If I asked you the value of $f(0, 0, 0)$, you would tell me it's $f(h(0), g(0, 0), 0)$, but you need a terminal case to avoid looping indefinitely.
I'm also not sure that $f$ would be defined everywhere.

Comment: Yeah now I see. If I define a terminal case then it becomes a constant function therefore the derivative would be 0  right?

Comment: Not at all. Consider this recursive function: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(n) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ for } n \le 1 \\ nf(n-1) & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$. It computes the factorial of $n$ recursively, but is not constant.